# Width decay and Fermi's golden rule

Tags: radiation, fermis-golden-rule

The width decay $\Gamma$ is the probability per time of a decay and the more accessible states there are in a decay, the more $\Gamma$ grows. Are these accessible states the decay's channels, or the states of phase space at a given energy related to the kinematics of the process, so $\rho(E_f)=\frac{dn}{dE_f}$?